# Select Min and Max from several bit variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table of teachers with 9 columns

```
TeacherID, TeacherName, Reception, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, Year5, ALevel
```

I need to concatenate the smallest and largest bit values (Reception - Year5) with 1, then display it in the select statement so its output as (in this case, Year 1, 2 and 3 are ticked): Y1 - Y3.

```
SELECT 
    TeacherID, TeacherName, 
    Reception + Year1 + Year2 + Year3 + Year4 + Year5 + ALevel as 'KeyStage' 
FROM Teachers
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Many thanks, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    TeacherID,
    TeacherName,
    CASE
        WHEN Reception > 0 THEN 'Re'
        WHEN Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1'
        WHEN Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2'
        WHEN Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3'
        WHEN Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4'
        WHEN Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5'
        WHEN ALevel > 0 THEN 'AL'
        ELSE '' END 
    + ' - ' +
    CASE
        WHEN ALevel > 0 THEN 'AL'
        WHEN Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5'
        WHEN Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4'
        WHEN Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3'
        WHEN Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2'
        WHEN Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1'
        WHEN Reception > 0 THEN 'Re'
        ELSE '' END AS Range
FROM
    Teachers
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this; *`First Case`* starting from `Reception` *for* `MinYear` and *`Second Case`* starting from `ALevel` for `MaxYear`. Also add `else` for each case to avoid getting null if none of them are 1

```
SELECT TeacherID, TeacherName, Reception,
       Case when Reception = 1 then 'R'
            when Year1 = 1 then 'Y1'
            ...
            when ALevel = 1 then 'AL'
            else ''
       End + ' - '
       Case when ALevel = 1 then 'AL'
            when Year5 = 1 then 'Y5'
            ...
            when Reception= 1 then 'R'
            else '' 
       End As KeyStage  
FROM Teachers
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't. Do it in your client code (php, c# whatever). Your spec is not clear either, what if years 1, 3 and 5 are ticked and 2 and 4 are not?

Comment: The above scenario could not happen, if a teacher is between Year 1 and 4, the teacher can work at year 3 weather Year 3 is ticked or not. Thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, I haven't tested it and you may need to make some changes. Note that if there is no bit checked then you will get a null value.  I would use the null because if nothing is checked then you don't have this weird dash there and you could use an isnull to change the value to what you want for no years selected.

```
SELECT TeacherID, 
   TeacherName,
   case when Reception = 1 then 'R'
        when Year1 = 1 then 'Y1'
        when Year2 = 1 then 'Y2'
        when Year3 = 1 then 'Y3'
        when Year4 = 1 then 'Y4'
        when Year5 = 1 then 'Y5'
        when ALevel = 1 then 'AL'
        else null end + ' - ' + 
   case when Reception = 1 then 'R'
        when Year1 = 1 then 'Y1'
        when Year2 = 1 then 'Y2'
        when Year3 = 1 then 'Y3'
        when Year4 = 1 then 'Y4'
        when Year5 = 1 then 'Y5'
        when ALevel = 1 then 'AL'
        else null end as 'KeyStage' 
FROM Teachers
```